# React.js Axios interceptors failed to retry the request, after the accessToken expired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to implement normal refresh tokens access tokens flow in a React application.

I have a custom hook called useRefreshToken, which is used to call the backend and set a new accessToken to the global state and return that token.

```
const useRefreshToken = ()=> {
  // @ts-ignore
  const {setAuth,auth} = useAuth();
  const refresh =async () => {
    const {data} = await axios.post('/token',{
      token:auth.refreshToken
    });
    
  // @ts-ignore
    setAuth(prev=>({...prev,accessToken:data.accessToken}));
    return data.accessToken
    
  }
  return refresh;
};

export default useRefreshToken;
```

Then I have a private Axios instance, to deal with a token updates.

```
const useAxiosPrivate = () => {
    const refresh = useRefreshToken();
    // @ts-ignore
    const { auth } = useAuth();

    useEffect(() => {

        const requestIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.use((config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
            console.log(config.headers)
            // @ts-ignore
            if (!config.headers['Authorization']) {
                // @ts-ignore
                config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${auth?.accessToken}`;
            }

            return config;
        }, (error) => Promise.reject(error))

        const responseintercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.use(response => response, async (error) => {
            const prevRequest = error.config;
            console.log("prevRequest?.sent", prevRequest?.sent)
            if (error?.response?.status === 403 && !prevRequest?.sent) {

                prevRequest.sent = true;
                const newAccessToken = await refresh();

                console.log("NEW ACCESS TOKEN SET", newAccessToken);
                prevRequest.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`;
                return axiosPrivate(prevRequest)
            }
            return Promise.reject(error)
        })

        return () => {
            axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.eject(requestIntercept)
            axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.eject(responseintercept)
        }


    }, [auth, refresh])


    return axiosPrivate;
}

export default useAxiosPrivate;
```

The problem is once the accessToken is expired and go this if block

```
 if (error?.response?.status === 403 && !prevRequest?.sent) {

                prevRequest.sent = true;
                const newAccessToken = await refresh();

                console.log("NEW ACCESS TOKEN SET", newAccessToken);
                prevRequest.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`;
                return axiosPrivate(prevRequest)
            }
```

I have notice the following things,

1. new access token is not set for the immediate request.
2. Immediate request headers, Content-Type is null and there is a header call [Object Object]
3. Also the `prevRequest.sent` is undefined, It has to be the value true.
   [image]

**BUT AFTER THAT IF I CALL THE SAME ENDPOINT AGAIN MANUALLY (BUTTON PRESS AGAIN) Things working as normal.**

What's wrong with this code?
Any help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by returning this:

`return axiosPrivate.request(prevRequest)`

Instead of:

`return axiosPrivate(prevRequest)`